# PHP-MongoDb: $pull shows error " Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using mongodb & want to remove ids of users from team collection. I am doing this as follows.

```
    $where = array('_id' => new MongoId($_SESSION['team_id']));
    $update = array('$pull' => array('log_report' => array('team_admins' =>  $teamId)));
    $mongoDb->update($where, $update);
```

It is showing me error

"**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value' in C:\xampp\htdocs\datacollection_web\core_php\app\php\processing\removeRightsAsAdminTeam.php:18"

My Mongodb database structure is this

```
"log_report": {
"team_admins": [
  "54c107f264363d840c000030",
  "54c2085764363d6c17000029",
  "54c2088d64363dfc12000029",
  "54c1075864363d081500002a"
],
```

I am not getting it???

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `$pull` needs to be a list, not a dict.

Using MongoDB's notation (becaue PHP's is noisy and I'm bad at PHP), here's what you're doing:

```
collection.update(..., {$pull: {log_report: {team_admins: team_id}}}
```

I'm assuming that your data looks like this:

```
{
    _id: "team1",
    log_report: {
        team_admins: ["team1", "team2", "team3"]
    }
}
```

And that you want to remove something from the `team_admins` list.

What you *should* be doing is this:

```
collection.update(..., {$pull: {log_report.team_admins: [team_id]}})
```

Note the use of dot notation. More information here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: $update = array('$pull' => array('log_report.team_admins' => $teamId));